# Normalized form of Triangule Inequality Extension

Tags: inequality

> How I can prove $$\mathit{\frac{\left\vert a-b\right\vert}{a+b}\leq\frac{\left\vert a-c\right\vert}{a+c}+\frac{\left\vert c-b\right\vert}{c+b}}$$ where $ a,b,c \in \mathbb N?$

Answer (score 2):

This nice inequality holds for non-negative **REAL** numbers $a,b,c$.

Suppose $a\ge b$.

Consider three cases:

1. $a\ge c \ge b$: we have $$RHS = \frac{a-c}{a+c}+\frac{c-b}{c+b}=\frac{2c(a-b)}{(a+c)(c+b)}.$$ It suffices to show that $$\frac{2c}{(a+c)(c+b)} \ge \frac{1}{a+b},$$ which is equivalent to $2c(a+b) \ge (a+c)(c+b) \Leftrightarrow (a-c)(c-b)\ge 0$, clearly true.
2. $c\ge a \ge b$: in this case we have $$\frac{a-b}{a+b} \le \frac{c-b}{c+b}$$
   (equivalent to $(a-b)(c+b)\le (a+b)(c-b) \Leftrightarrow 2b(c-a)\ge 0)$, and thus the original inequality is true.
3. $a \ge b \ge c$: in this case, similarly we have $$\frac{a-b}{a+b} \le \frac{a-c}{a+c}.$$

We are done.